# iText not extract Shruti Text Correctly using java

Tags: java, pdf, text, itext

I want to Extract Shruti Text from pdf file and write new pdf. I am using 
iText but it can't Extract Proper text,so what is the solution for it???

i am using iText 5.4 lib for this

iText is show  in new pdf ',' '-','_' and blanks instaed of Shruti font text

```
Code That I am Using is,
//for extract text From pdf
  try {
     PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(file path,password);
     String iTextContent = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfreader,1);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(JFileChooserDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }



  //write new pdf file
   try{
       Document docNew = new Document();     
       PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(docNew,new FileOutputStream("D:\\demo.pdf"));
     docNew.open();

     BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("D:\\DeskTop\\Pdf Box jar\\shruti.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
     Font f = new Font(bf,5);
     docNew.add(new Paragraph(newStr,f));

     docNew.close();
     writer.close();
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please share your PDF.